# PHP: Can't find rows from mySql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im new with PHP and mysql. I tried to make a login system but I'm stuck and can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

I got it working once but then i added some more features and now I cant get it to work anymore. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_ERROR ^ E_WARNING);
require('./pages/connections.php');

if ($con){   
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  {

    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

    $sql_query="SELECT Username FROM user WHERE Username='$username' and Password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 1)
    {
      $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;

      header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<div class="center-block" name="errormsgphp" id="errormsgphp">Invalid username or password.</div>';
    }
  }
}
else 
  echo '<div class="center-block" name="errormsgphp" id="errormsgphp">Error with database connection.</div>';
?>
```

It keeps throwing me to the else loop from `if($count == 1)` aka. cant find from database right?

I'm almost 100% sure the database is formatted correctly and working because I can register users there and i got this login working just a little earlier.
If someone could spot my error then i would be very glad! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out put errors, they will help

Comment: Definitely learn to [indent your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Styles). This is unnecessarily hard/annoying to read.

Comment: What is inside $con ? Please mention the query in $con?

Comment: what features did you add??

Comment: inside $con is: 
<?php
//server, username, password, database
$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");
?>

Comment: Was the content in $con same as above initially?...I mean was it the same when the above code was working too or did you change it to that recently?

Comment: I added some error detection and redirecting from home.php if not logged in. Also logout link if logged in.

Comment: I edit the post with a correct indentation of the code.

Comment: I only changed the database name from orginal to "db_name" I'm testing this with local server before going live.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT email, password, status FROM agent_register WHERE email='".$email_input."' && password='".$password_input."' && status = 1 ";
  $result= mysql_query($sql);  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); use like this

Comment: Try this, mention `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");` before the if statement.

Comment: check your query your query is right or wrong echo the sql line. after that that copy your query & run in your database

Comment: Cant seem to get it work with these.

Comment: can u show me the error

Comment: This is working inside the phpmyadmin mysql query:
SELECT Username FROM user WHERE Username='Test_User' AND Password='qwe123'

Comment: it means you are mistaking in database connectivity check your database connectivity

Comment: check your $ row what you are getting in this $row

Comment: The $row echoes empty so there is something wrong with the connection after all?

Comment: use like this print_R($row); this is an array it will not give any output if u will write echo $row

Comment: make new file and keep this code $conn_error = 'Could not connect';
 $mysql_host = 'localhost';
 $mysql_user = 'root';
 $mysql_pass = '';
 $mysql_db = 'rent';
 
 if (!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
  die(mysql_error());
 }

Comment: after that include this file like include('filename');

Comment: cant seem to get print_R($row); to display anything either.

Comment: check your database connectivity

Comment: make new file database.php keep this code in this file:   <?php
 $conn_error = 'Could not connect';
 $mysql_host = 'localhost';
 $mysql_user = 'root';
 $mysql_pass = '';
 $mysql_db = 'rent';
 
 if (!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
  die(mysql_error());
 }
?>

Comment: include("database.php"); include this file in your php file after your starting the session

Comment: check your database also you have row or not

Comment: you can also check your database file write echo include('database.php'); if it will return 1 then your connectivity is right otherwise you have a connectivity problem

Comment: have you got your answer??

Comment: " echo include('database.php'); " does echo 1 both before and after the $count check, but still cant find the data from database :/ I think im gonna quit for the day. Still thanks for your answears!

Comment: just do one thing print_R this line mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: please can u post your connectivity file code

Answer (score 0):

try like this i hope this will help you

```
$sql = "SELECT email, password, status FROM agent_register WHERE email='".$email_input."' && password='".$password_input."' && status = 1 ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($row > 0){
        $details = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['flag'] = true;   
        echo "<pre>"; print_R($details);
    }
```

Comment: Use Mysqli instead of Mysql

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I got it working now but absolutely no idea what was wrong. I just kept ctrl+z back so much that I found the earlier part that was working. Only difference was that I usedearlier `if($count==1)` instead of `if($count == 1)`. Maybe it was that or my xampp was messing with me or something... but still thanks to all responses!